# Create a view Filter SharePoint list for items I - [Me] - haven't rated

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, modern-experience, rating

Is there a way to filter (and subsequently create a view for) a SharePoint list to show items that the current user hasn't rated?

For example, in the list below I would like to create a view that would only show Wednesday and Thursday as I haven't yet submitted a rating for them - even if others have rated these items.

[image: List with "Days of the week" and "Rating (0-5)" fields]

I'm guessing it has something to do with the Rated by property but can't quite figure out how to access this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Select rating column -> Filter -> Select empty -> Apply.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks - but what if others have already rated these items? Will they still show as (Empty) if I haven't rated them?

Comment: These items will not show as empty.